# How do I share ASP.NET code between different web apps on different servers

Tags: asp.net, iis

We have several different applications built in ASP.NET that run different parts of the same platform. I.e. An administration web app, a public facing web app and some non-web applications (I.e. .exe apps) that all need to perform some shared functionality.

Ideally I don't want to clone the code due to maintainability issues. Until recent we had all these running on the same server so we could just put some DLLs in the global assembly cache  (although we never got around to this and did end up with cloned code).

Now we've moved the various parts of the system to separate servers, putting shared code in the GAC won't solve the cloned code issue. Is there a way to share code across multiple servers without making copies?

Comment: Implement your shared code as a Web Service ( options : WCF/REST/ASMX) and use it in your applications.

Comment: A web service would work but I think it may be bit slow

Answer (score 1):

You want to perform a distributed execution, because you want to launch and executable in a different machine, and this is probably easily feasible doing a shared folder (but you should be really careful about security).

Another solution is to create a web service that exposes a method to launch the executable or run the task you want to share. In this way you have only one place to update the code.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three options:

1. A single solution which contains several projects, including another project containing the platform.
2. Having the platform/engine on a different solution and share the dll with each project (you have to update each time).
3. Provide an API which is shared with all projects.

Answer (score 0):

Are you guys already connected to TeamExplorer? Assuming your IDE has it. Otherwise try to publish the code to the same server.

Comment: Yes we are using visual studio and Team Foundation Service